# FirebaseAuth getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@1a8f272

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    resConfigs "en"
    applicationId "com.yrrsolutions.ram"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.0.2'
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.0.2"
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.1.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v8:0.7.0'
}
```

project.gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

i am trying to do phone auth but i am getting the error "I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@1a8f272"
Can u help me to resolve this.
I am using ANDROIDX

Comment: Have you added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` as the last line in your `app.gradle` file?

Comment: i tried it then also i am getting same error

Comment: and error is "getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@b0ff37d"

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to resolve this error?

Comment: actually the solution is to go to your root flutter project , and type , 'flutter get packages'.
because sometimes you forget to do it (humans forget) .